# dynamically render a component in lazy loaded module with AOT throws cant find component factory

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, lazy-loading

### Current behavior

I declared those dynamic components as entry components in the module where I also want to render them. With JIT it works fine.
Following structure has the part of my app I want to render them: `app -> home (lazy) -> contracts (lazy) -> search`.

So I added those components to the module I use for the `search component/route`. When I'm compiling with AOT, everytime I visit the search route, the app tells me there is no component factory. Of course I searched google and found some results:

I tried adding them to the `ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS` provider, I tried to import a ModuleWithProviders with `.forRoot()` in my app.module and I also tried simply importing and declaring my dynamic and all of its dependant components in the root module (app.module). Everything resulting in the same error.

I declare my dynamic components as entry components like so:

`@NgModule({
  imports: [SharedComponentsModule, FinoSchemaFormsModule, TabGroupModule, FinoInputModule],
  declarations: [EnergySearchSettingsComponent, DslSearchSettingsComponent, MobileSearchSettingsComponent, ComparisonDetailSectionComponent],
  entryComponents: [EnergySearchSettingsComponent, DslSearchSettingsComponent, MobileSearchSettingsComponent],
  exports: [EnergySearchSettingsComponent, DslSearchSettingsComponent, MobileSearchSettingsComponent, ComparisonDetailSectionComponent],
  providers: [CategoryMappingProvider]
})
export class ComparisonComponentsModule { }`

This module gets imported in the `SearchModule`, where also my `SearchComponent` is declared. In this component I want to render those components dynamically using the `ComponentFactoryResolver` I inject in the `SearchComponent`.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.searchSettingsComponent = this.comparisonService.getSearchComponent(); // returns either EnergySearchSettingsComponent, DslSearchSettingsComponent or MobileSearchSettingsComponent
    let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(searchSettingsComponent);
    this.searchSettingsComponent = this.searchContainer.createComponent(componentFactory);
    this.searchSettingsComponent.instance.comparisonSettings = comparisonSettings;
    this.searchSettingsComponent.instance.onSave.subscribe(settings => this.saveSearchSettings(settings));
}
```

The `SearchComponent` is the routing component of the `search` route, which is a child route of my `contract` route, which gets lazy loaded. This again is a child route of my home route (also lazy loaded) and this belongs to the main route.

### Environment

```
Angular version: 5.2.4

For Tooling issues:
- Node version: 8.11.3
- Platform:  Mac
```

Comment: This happened to me as well, but when i imported my dynamic components in app.module and add those to entryComponent, instead of feature module it just resolved...

Comment: Yeah I already tried this, but did not work unfortunately. But to be honest, this cant be the correct solution since angular's modules lose their purpose by doing this.

Comment: That's why it is in the comment not in the answer section :)

Comment: Can you please provide a minimum reproduction using stackblitz.

Answer (score 3):

It must be pretty simple. Just create the `SharedModule` and put all reusable dynamic component in it, **export those components from SharedModule** and import this `Module` in all required. Lazy loaded Modules.

Since it is imported direct to the Module, it must be available while creating the Dynamic Component.

Comment: That would mean I import this components in all of my modules, even though I just use them in one lazy loaded module. That does not sound right to me.

Comment: No, you just need to import into the Module you want to use the Component in.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating angular to latest 6.1.10? With version 5 I had issues with lazy loaded modules.

I had a similar task, and it worked fine under 6.1.4.

I've created a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vf4jry) for you under 7.0.1

I've created both cases

1. Dynamic component is declared in the module which will create the dynamic component
2. Dynamic component is declared in a shared module and imported in the lazy-loaded module which will create dynamic components. You can create a shared module for every dynamic component, so you import only one component in a lazy loaded module

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel as though there is enough information in your question to give you the exact answer to the problem you are facing.

I was able to create a solution with, what I feel is a similar setup to yours that you could use to solve your problem or to ask a more pointed question.

[TLDR: Full GitHub repo here](https://github.com/PdUi/stack-overflow-answer-repos/tree/master/ng-dynamic)

I created an app structure as follows:

`app/
  app.module
  app.component
  /dynamic-provider                  --contains component that is dynamically loading other components
                                     --module is lazy loaded by dynamic-one module
    dynamic-loader.module
    slot.component
  /dynamic-one                       --contains lazy loaded module
                                     --module is lazy loaded by app module
    dynamic-one.module
  /dynamic-loader                    --contains a component to be dynamically loaded
    dynamic-provider.module
    one.component
    provider.service`

app.module looks as follows

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'dynamic-loader', loadChildren: './dynamic-one/dynamic-one.module#DynamicOneModule' },
      { path: '', component: AppComponent }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

dynamic-one.module looks as follows

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: '', loadChildren: '../dynamic-loader/dynamic-loader.module#DynamicLoaderModule' }
    ])
  ]
})
export class DynamicOneModule {
  constructor() {
    console.log('one');
  }
}
```

dynamic-loader.module looks as follows

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { DynamicProviderModule } from '../dynamic-provider/dynamic-provider.module';

import { SlotComponent } from './slot.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ SlotComponent ],
  imports: [
    DynamicProviderModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: '', component: SlotComponent }
    ])
  ]
})
export class DynamicLoaderModule { }
```

dynamic-provider.module looks as follows

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { OneComponent } from './one.component';
import { ProviderService } from './provider.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ OneComponent ],
  entryComponents: [ OneComponent ],
  exports: [ OneComponent ],
  providers: [ ProviderService ]
})
export class DynamicProviderModule { }
```

As you state, your dynamic creation of components is working when the module isn't loaded, so I haven't included that code here(though it is in the repo for completeness). As can be seen here though, the app module lazy loads the dynamic-one module which in turn lazy loads the dynamic-loader module. The dynamic-loader module dynamically creates components from the dynamic-provider module.

How this differs from your implementation is very hard to tell as you have provided only a small amount of information. I hope this helps you find the missing piece you are looking for though!

Answer (score 0):

> Creating shared modules allows you to organize and streamline your
>   code. You can put commonly used directives, pipes, and components into
>   one module and then import just that module wherever you need it in
>   other parts of your app.
>
> By re-exporting CommonModule and FormsModule, any other module that imports this SharedModule, gets access to directives like NgIf and NgFor from CommonModule and can bind to component properties with [(ngModel)], a directive in the FormsModule.

EX:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { SharedModule } from '../../shared/shared.module';
import { EntryModalComponent  } from './entry-modal.component';

@NgModule({
 imports: [
   CommonModule,
   SharedModule,
   ReactiveFormsModule
 ],
declarations: [ EntryModalComponent ],
entryComponents: [ EntryModalComponent ],
exports: [ EntryModalComponent ]
})
export class EntryModalModule { }
```

Now you can use this EntryModalComponent for dynamic loading in some other component after importing the module where it's defined.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions Angular has updated a lot of staff about lazy loaded modules. And with high probability this trouble is fixed now.